# Vertex selection without edge highlighting?

Tags: mesh, interface, 3d-view, vertices

Selecting a cube's vertex displays an orange point (sure it is vertex) with its connected three edges (edges highlighted as orange to black gradient).

For example, selecting a vertex in 3ds Max only highlights the vertex point.

In Blender, when selecting a vertex, it does highlight the vertex point **with its connected edges**. I don't want to see gradient orange edges.

Is there an option to change how vertices are highlighted?

Answer (score 5):

What is or is not shown is in the *Properties Region* <kbd>N</kbd> on the right hand side of the 3D viewport. Untick edges in *Mesh Display → Overlays*:

[image]

You can show/hide vertexes, edges, vertex normals, face normals, etc.