# Component Selection Distance

Tags: modeling, customization, selection-tools

When selecting components, is there a way to control the "selection distance/area"? I don't want to select a component, even if I click ~20 pixels away from it.

[image: selection distance]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding the highlighted edges see here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/vertex-selection-without-edge-highlighting

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no setting for this. You can see in the Interface tab of the user preferences menu that there's a 'hotspot' distance for the handles of manipulators and similar settings for Pie menus. This is probably where you'd expect to find such a setting and it isn't exposed there.

[image: Interface]

Maybe more substantially, in [this mirror](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/mesh/editmesh_select.c#L446) of the Blender source code on line 446 a comment mentions that the below function uses a hardcoded value (line 392) of 5px for unselected vertices. This isn't necessarily the only way to select vertices in Blender but it seems to be the default.