# Edit Mode: disable closest selection

Tags: shortcut

Is it possible avoid Blender 2.79 from selecting the closest vertex/edge/face in Edit Mode?

I find that even when clicking well outside of my model, the closest possible target often seem to selected, I have no idea why Blender would behave this way.

Thx!

Update: the behavior I am seeing: https://streamable.com/y447y

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I'm not quite sure to really understand the behaviour you would like to see: you would like to able to click whitout selecting? what should the click action perform instead?

Comment: @Carlo I am not able to explain it in words, so I am just going to add a video showing my issue (see update)

Comment: So you would like to decrease the radius of the click slection to be able to clik near the edge without selecting? May I ask what's the reason behind clicking with the selection button without actually wanting to select? BTW, here's a similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107815/component-selection-distance

Comment: @Carlo it's intuitive to click somewhere else to de-select the items. and I am quite surprise that question never got an answer!

Comment: In 2.79 developers preferred to use a dedicated key for deselection. I think the few peole who have seen the question did not have an aswer. The issue isn't ruining the workflow, as the deselction is based on a different approach, so it's not seen as a big problem and few people were wandering about changing the threshold distance as clicking far a way from object currently has no puropose.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer as **there is currently no solution to my specific problem in 2.79**. But I did find some alternative to de-selection.

I have created a keymap based on the 2.80 "Industry Standard Keymap" proposal in case people ran into the same issue as me.

https://gist.github.com/bitinn/22f6fefe026d8d9e83468864edb8f835